# Angular routing lazy loading not working for bookmarked routes

Tags: angular, routes, angular-lazyloading

I use lazy loading modules with routing for first level naviagtion. One module for each first level nagigation element. This works fine.

I load the child navigation (second level) items dynamically using lazyloading. In principal routing works but once a user bookmarks a route for one second level element the application cannot find the correct.

Any ideas on this?